# STL algorithm similar to transform which allows access to previously transformed element, similar to accumulate

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, containers

Is there an STL algorithm which allows me to apply a function to each element in a range, transforming the element, with the previously transformed element as input?

I am thinking something like this (obviously does not work since the second iterator will be invalid):

```cpp
struct Input
{
    int width;
};

struct Output
{
    int x;
    int width;
};

Output transform_input(const Input &input, const Output &previous)
{
    return { previous.x + previous.width, input.width };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Input> input = { { 30 }, { 60 }, { 10 } };
    std::vector<Output> output;

    std::transform(std::begin(input)
        , std::end(input)
        , std::prev(std::begin(output))
        , std::back_inserter(output)
        , transform_input
        );
}
```

Expected result here is for `output` to contain 3 elements of type `Output`, with the following content:

- Element 0 where `x == 0` and `width == 30`
- Element 1 where `x == 30` and `width == 60`
- Element 2 where `x == 90` and `width == 10`

For this to work, I imagine the algorithm would have to allow me to specify a seed, alternatively default construct one for me.

I have already looked at `transform` and `adjacent_difference`.

Using `transform` might work with some kind of custom iterator, or perhaps there is one built-in to STL which I could use?

While `adjacent_difference` seemed promising, it will only give me access to the previous element for the input iterator.

If there's no built-in algorithm satisfying my requirements, what is an algorithm such as this called?

Comment: Make `transform_output` a function object  (e.g. a data structure with an `operator()` that stores the previous value in a member of the structure or, possibly, a lambda that captures a reference to a variable from the caller).   You'll obviously need to work out how to handle the first call (when there is no previous value).   The clumsy approach would be for a function like you have, with one argument (as required) that stores the value in a static variable.

Comment: That is certainly one approach, yeah. I did consider it, but would prefer a more functional approach. I might go about rolling my own reusable algorithm if there is none, but I am not sure what to call it :)

Comment: What do you mean by a "more functional approach"?   Your constraint to do this in an algorithm rather than in the function that does a transformation seems ..... arbitrary.

Comment: I mean that I want to keep my code pure, without any visible changes to state. If I would go about rolling my own algorithm I would implement it as a recursive function, which I personally consider a more elegant solution. I understand that it might seem arbitrary.

Comment: @Scheff The problem is that `std::accumulate` will only produce a single result, while I want a collection.

Comment: I see. Sorry, didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::transform` and pass a lambda that captures your output container.

```
std::transform(std::begin(input)
    , std::end(input)
    , std::back_inserter(output)
    , [&](auto& input) {
        if (output.empty()) {
            return transform_input(input, {});
        } else {
            return transform_input(input, output.back());
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a clever solution :)

Comment: Note this code won't work as-is if the `output` is not initially empty. It would make more sense to test if `input` came from the first iterator, or just give the lambda its own counter or boolean flag that increments/becomes true after each call so the lambda can test for the first call. On a side note, for the first `input` value, I would use a separate function: `Output transform_input_first(const Input &input) { return { 0, input.width }; }`